# install bettery drivers for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: power-management, battery

I have recently installed ubuntu and it seems ve[]ry power consuming. after installing it it heats up too much.
is there any battery drivers available here for ubuntu.
my leaptop configuration is:
sony vaio i5 2nd gen
4 gb ram
500 mb nvidia.

Comment: Which devices are heating up too much? [How to check](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto). Have you installed any power managment tool like [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Batteries do not have drivers. As mentioned in the comments you might want to try installing TLP.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

TLP will automatically start  upon system startup, but to avoid having to restart the system to get it running for the first time, you can start it (required only the first time) using the following command:

```
sudo tlp start
```

I have a laptop too, power hungry i7 and 17" screen and get 3-4 hours battery life using TLP. Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

You will also want to make sure you have the correct drivers installed. Go to settings >> Software & Updates in the last tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/76oXj.png